# Network storage and backup

Tags: samba, robocopy, iscsi

I had a MS 2003 server on my home LAN as an AD DC (inc DNS). It's main purpose was to share files (photos, music, family docs etc) and to act as a backup facility for the desktops. laptops on the LAN. Every evening Robocopy would run as a scheduled task. on the desktops/laptops, to backup the "My Documents" and Desktop and Thunderbird etc, unlike Samaba. Then during the night the 2003 server would backup the "Data" drive to a 1TB USB drive. Each Desktop/Laptop had Mapped drives for Music, photos and "public" etc so we had a common stoarage area. This has worked very well for years but as 2003 server is now at at end I decided to have a re-think and I don't really need an internal DNS server or DC but do want to retain the network shares and backup facility. Devices on my LAN are mainly Windows 7 & 8 but also a couple of 'droid tablets and an Ipad-Air

With this in mind, I've been playing with CentOS 7 for the past few weeks and have got BIND(DNS) working fine (although not really needed) along with SAMBA. In principle it all works great but Samba seems to be a bit flakey, in that it doesn't work all the time and I'm having problems with permissions! My second problem is Robocopy doesn't appear to like ext3. I've come across iSCSI and think that would be useful but it appears that it won't allow more than one user at a time to access the "share"(?)

My thinking now is to format the 1TB "data" drive as 2 partitions and use NTFS for the SAMBA shares (I've installed something on Centos that apparently allows NTFS to be mounted) and then use iSCSI on the other partition and use this for the backups.

I've never used iSCSI but it's apparently Robocopy friendly :-)

I'd appreciate and comments or advice, I'm at that stage of my life cycle where I'm looking for simplicity and ease of use. I don't mind learning a few new tricks but I'm now in the slow learners clubs :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could run Robocopy jobs/tasks automatically in each device, any time you want.
You can set a homegroup and share folders with this group, setting everything you need on windows 7.
Android tablets and iPads can backup itself once plugged on PC or Mac, with a little help of Google yo can find how easy it is.
If it sounds good I add the necessary stuff in my answer.